Clangd не находит атрибут assume
Использую в качестве IDE neovim, в нем настроен в качестве LSP clangd.
Для сборки проекта использую meson, в котором явно установлен стандарт c++26:
project('test_gccjit', 'cpp',
  default_options: 'cpp_std=c++26'  
)

В compile_commands также присутствует флаг "-std=c++26" и находит функции, доступные в c++26.
#include <print>
[[nodiscard]] //ОК, без предупреждений
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    [[assume(argc > 0)]]; //clang: Unknown attribute 'assume' ignored
    std::print("Hello world!\n"); //Все ОК, находит
    return 0;
}

clangd --version возвращает "18.1.8" 
Согласно сайту cppreference, assume должен быть реализован.

Так и должно быть, или надо специфически как-то настраивать clangd? Добавят ли в clangd поддержку всех атрибутов?


"Согласно сайту cppreference, assume должен быть реализован." - Где? Я в таблице вижу надпись, что он реализован в Clang 19. Нужно обновляться... Ну и в целом, такое можно проверять компиляцией Clang-ом той же версии с теми же флагами. Если попробуете, увидите точно такой же ворнинг от компилятора.
